# Camera taken image is not showing in image view

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue while displaying camera captured image in an image view where delegates are set and being called "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo".

I have two buttons for the user interaction (camera picture & from gallery), once I take picture from camera and then select any other image from gallery; the camera picture taken earlier is shown for a second. I tried searching a lot but no luck so far.

Can anyone please advise what am I missing. Following is the code for reference.

```
 @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.openCamera()
  }

  @IBAction func galleryButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.openGallary()

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialLayout()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.lblPreview.isHidden = true
    self.imageTake.isHidden = true
    self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
  }

  //
  //MARK: - Internal Methods
  func initialLayout() {

    self.cameraButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.galleryButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.uploadButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20

  }


//MARK: - Open the camera
  func openCamera(){

    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)){

      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
      //If you dont want to edit the photo then you can set allowsEditing to false
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
      imagePicker.delegate = self
      imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
      imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
      self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
      let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

  //MARK: - Choose image from camera roll

  func openGallary(){

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }


extension UploadTimesheetViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:  [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{

      self.lblPreview.isHidden = false
      self.imageTake.isHidden = false
      self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        self.imageTake.image = editedImage
        self.imageTake.setNeedsLayout()
      })

      // self.imageTake.image = editedImage
    }

    //Dismiss the UIImagePicker after selection
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter here? when using it , editedImage will be set to imageView after a second and being so curious why do you need setNeedsLayout ?

Comment: I used it for testing purposes , by this I can see after taking a picture from camera, image view is not updated but when I select a picture from gallery, camera picture shown properly and right after a second gallery picture is overrides and shows properly. I will remove once the solution is provided. The problem is camera picture is there but image view is not showing it until I select a picture from gallery and only then camera picture is shown for a second and then gallery picture is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Update your delegate method like this,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    var finalImage:UIImage?

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        finalImage = image
    }else {
        finalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    self.lblPreview.isHidden = false
    self.imageTake.isHidden = false
    self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
    self.imageTake.image = finalImage

    //Dismiss the UIImagePicker after selection
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Hi Thilina, I tried it but still the same result, imgageview is not showing camera taken picture, it only shows for a second when I try to select an image from gallery. I am still not sure why it is not updating

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. Just updating the answer so if anyone is having the same issue should know what was the actual problem.

Once picker is dismissed a viewwillappear will be called where I have hid the image view and hence the reason it was not displaying it for the first time.

If I remove the code from viewwillappear and add that properties code to viewedload then all works fine.

The issue was once the picker is dismissed , viewillapear was called and that was creating the issue.